# I cant access my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello im new to php and Mysql im stuck here anyone please help me.

**Error message :**

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'suren'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/nanot142/public_html/index.php on line 7
Database connection failed : Access denied for user 'suren'@'localhost' (using password: YES)(Access denied for user 'suren'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
```

**My code**

```
<?php

$dbhost ="localhost";
$dbuser ="suren";
$dbpass ="password";
$dbname ="nano";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     die( "Database connection failed : " . mysqli_connect_error() . "(" . mysqli_connect_error() . ")" );}

?>

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM subjects";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>

<div id="main"> 
   <div id="navigation">
      &nbsp;
   </div>
   <div id="page">
      <h2>Manage Content</h2>
   </div>
</div>

<?php include("includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
<?php mysqli_close($connection); ?>
```

Comment: if `suren` is denied of access, surely `root` will be allowed right? (based on your codes `$dbuser ="root";`) / or incorrect password

Comment: Have to agree with Ghost's comment, does your user `suren` exist and is the password correct? does he have access to this DB? etc?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake dbuser is suren i just re-edited the code still cant access please help me with this.

Comment: YES @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: even $dbuser = "root" is not accesseble the same problem acess denied. @Ghost

Comment: Have you got PHPMyAdmin? Guessing that is how you created the database? What do you use to login to PHPMyAdmin? Use those same credentials. If it doesn't ask, then can you connect using root with no password. If you can login to PHPMyAdmin or some other interface - have a look at the users section and make sure the user/pass are correct and that the user has the rights to access this particular database etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this..

```
$dbhost ="localhost";
$dbuser ="root";  //this is the username using to login localhost/phpmyadmin
$dbpass =""; //this is the password using to login localhost/phpmyadmin..if no                     //password leave it blank as given
$dbname ="test"; // this your database name

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

else{
    echo "success";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Haseena PA but it doesnt work for me it says Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\nano\manage_content.php on line 7
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)